# Efficient way to get DISTINCT rows of Table A when JOINing with Table B

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, distinct

Simple problem. Given example tables:

**Table A:**

```
id | type
---+-----
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
```

**Table B:**

```
id | a_id | type
---+------+-----
1  | 1    | X
2  | 2    | Y
3  | 1    | X
4  | 3    | Z
```

(there are additional columns, which I omitted, in order to clarify the problem)

**The query:**

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a a
INNER JOIN b b ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.type = 'X'
```

**Result**:

```
id | type
---+-----
1  | A
1  | A
```

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6138f/1

But I only want to have distinct rows of Table A. I know, I could do `SELECT DISTINCT a.*`, but our Table A has about 40 columns, and this `SELECT` can return 100-10000 rows. Isn't that extremely slow, if the database has to compare each column?

Or is MySQL intelligent enough, to just focus on the Primary Key for the DISTINCT operation?

Thanks in advance `:)`

Comment: "Or is MySQL intelligent enough, to just focus on the Primary Key for the DISTINCT operation?" = NO. `select distinct` is a "row operator" and it considers all parts of each row.

Comment: Stupid DB. It should simply look for the first `unique` (and maybe `indexed`) field (in most cases `id`) and use that for `distinct`. Same result, but 99% less comparisons. ... Maybe I should switch to Postgres, there I could say: *just apply distinct to column `x`*

Comment: You can tell sql dbs to use just a field, or a nominated set of fields, to be distinct. It is `group by` that you use for this, not `select distinct`. In Postgres `select distinct` is the same; `select distinct ON` is different.

Comment: I just tested it, and you are right: `SELECT a.* FROM a a JOIN b b ON b.a_id = a.id GROUP BY a.id` works. I alway thought that I can only `SELECT` the fields which are also within the `GROUP BY` statement and additionally aggregates of those columns (like `sum` oder `max`). ... I remember that sometime ago I got MySQL Errors when trying to use `GROUP BY` and selecting fields which could not be grouped.

Comment: Don't get too excited, yes you can do exactly what you just said in MySQL. But in truth you are likely to get unexpected results. It is still best practice to nominate all the fields you are grouping by and then  handle the others via an aggregate function. Shortcut methods give shortcut results.

Comment: Yes of course, also in my mind `GROUP BY` stands (mostly) for aggregation. And my case here has got nothing to do with aggregation. But I don't understand how `GROUP BY` should return unexpected results in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists` instead of an explicit join:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.a_id = a.id and b.type = 'x');
```

For performance, create an index on `tableb(a_id, type)`.